# SQL 2008 Install Failure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a fresh install of Windows Server 2003 R2 32-bit with all of the latest windows updates. I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 Standard x86 on it to prepare for Microsoft Team Foundation Server. So far I have been unsuccessful as the installation keeps failing with the error message:

> A Severe error occurred on the current command.

This is what I believe to be the relevant section of the Details.txt log file.

```
2010-10-15 09:51:26 Slp: --SafeSqlCommand: declare @ServerName nvarchar(255) if not 

exists (select * from sysservers) begin select @ServerName = Convert(nvarchar(255), SERVERPROPERTY(N'ServerName')) execute sys.sp_addserver @ServerName, local end
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: SqlException: Message:A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
LineNumber:0
2010-10-15 09:51:31 SQLEngine: Copying 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2010-10-15T09.51.31.txt' ...
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to set file full path to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize directory path 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if file 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG' exists
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to copy file 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG' to file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2010-10-15T09.51.31.txt'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if file 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG' exists
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize directory path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2010-10-15T09.51.31.txt'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to set file full path to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2010-10-15T09.51.31.txt'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize directory path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2010-10-15T09.51.31.txt'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if directory path 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG' is equal to path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2010-10-15T09.51.31.txt'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if directory path 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG' is equal to path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2010-10-15T09.51.31.txt'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize directory path 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'
2010-10-15 09:51:31 Slp: Sco: Attempting to normalize directory path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\SQLServer_ERRORLOG_2010-10-15T09.51.31.txt'
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get security descriptor for file 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if file 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG' exists
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Sco: Returning security descriptor O:NSG:NSD:AI(A;ID;FA;;;NS)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3546625195-1536672478-4029743794-1010)(A;ID;0x1201ff;;;S-1-5-21-3546625195-1536672478-4029743794-1011)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Sco: Attempting to dispose script
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Sco: Attempting to disconnect script
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Current SqlServer Connection closed...
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigRC and scenario ConfigRC.
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigRC and scenario ConfigRC.
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.SqlScriptExecution.ExecuteScriptStatement(String& scriptStatement)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SafeSqlCommand.ExecNonQuery(String script)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineScriptExecution.RunEngineInstallScripts(SqlServiceInstallScriptParameters scriptParameters)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlDatabaseServiceConfig.Install(SqlServiceInstallScriptParameters scriptParameters)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineDBStartConfig.ConfigSQLServerSystemDatabases(EffectiveProperties properties, Boolean isConfiguringTemplateDBs, Boolean useInstallInputs)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineDBStartConfig.DoCommonDBStartConfig(ConfigActionTiming timing)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineDBStartConfig.Install(ConfigActionTiming timing, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcb)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.PrivateConfigurationBase.Execute(ConfigActionScenario scenario, ConfigActionTiming timing, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcbCurrent)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SqlFeatureConfigBase.Execute(ConfigActionScenario scenario, ConfigActionTiming timing, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcbCurrent)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException.
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: Message: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
2010-10-15 09:51:32 Slp: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded..
2010-10-15 09:51:34 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_Microsoft SQL Server.reg_
2010-10-15 09:51:34 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_Windows_CurrentVersion_Uninstall.reg_
2010-10-15 09:51:34 Slp: Sco: Attempting to write hklm registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer to file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20101015_092804\Registry_SOFTWARE_Microsoft_MSSQLServer.reg_
2010-10-15 09:51:57 Slp: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
2010-10-15 09:51:59 Slp: Watson bucket for exception based failure has been created
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Completed Action: SqlEngineDBStartConfigAction_install_configrc_Cpu32, returned False
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get instance feature flag UpgradeIncomplete for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\UpgradeIncompleteState
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQL_Engine_Core_Inst
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get feature configuration state for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get instance feature flag ConfigurationState for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\ConfigurationState
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQL_Engine_Core_Inst
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get instance feature flag UpgradeIncomplete for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\UpgradeIncompleteState
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQL_Engine_Core_Inst
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get feature configuration state for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get instance feature flag ConfigurationState for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\ConfigurationState
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQL_Engine_Core_Inst
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get instance feature flag UpgradeIncomplete for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\UpgradeIncompleteState
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQL_Engine_Core_Inst
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get feature configuration state for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get instance feature flag ConfigurationState for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst, instance MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\ConfigurationState
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQL_Engine_Core_Inst
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Error: Action "SqlEngineDBStartConfigAction_install_configrc_Cpu32" failed during execution.
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Action "AgentScriptConfiguration_install_rc_Cpu32" will return false due to the following conditions:
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Condition "Feature dependency condition for action: AgentScriptConfiguration_install_rc_Cpu32 The condition tests feature: SQL_Engine_Core_Inst_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu32. There are 10 dependant features. The feature is tested for results: ValidateResult, Result." did not pass as it returned false and true was expected.
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Condition is false because the required feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu32 failed in result Result
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Error: Action "AgentScriptConfiguration_install_rc_Cpu32" failed during execution.
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Action "RS_RunInstallScriptsAction_Cpu32" will return false due to the following conditions:
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Condition "Feature dependency condition for action: RS_RunInstallScriptsAction_Cpu32 The condition tests feature: SQL_Engine_Core_Inst_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu32. There are 10 dependant features. The feature is tested for results: ValidateResult, Result." did not pass as it returned false and true was expected.
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Condition is false because the required feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu32 failed in result Result
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Error: Action "RS_RunInstallScriptsAction_Cpu32" failed during execution.
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Action "SqlEngineDBStopConfigAction_install_configrc_Cpu32" will return false due to the following conditions:
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Condition "Feature dependency condition for action: SqlEngineDBStopConfigAction_install_configrc_Cpu32 The condition tests feature: SQL_Engine_Core_Inst_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu32. There are 10 dependant features. The feature is tested for results: ValidateResult, Result." did not pass as it returned false and true was expected.
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Condition is false because the required feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst_sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu32 failed in result Result
2010-10-15 09:54:07 Slp: Error: Action "SqlEngineDBStopConfigAction_install_configrc_Cpu32" failed during execution.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is blocking a bunch of work and I've searched all over to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not know what was causing this issue but I was able to work around it by installing component by component, one at a time, in the following order:

1. Database Engine
2. Full Text
3. Analysis Services
4. Reporting Services
5. Client Connectivity
6. Client Tools